# Calculating position in Bitmap Image

Tags: android, bitmap

I have floor plan image and draw it into UI with bitmap in scaled example 500 x 500 pixel. The actual image is 700x700 pixel.

With normal size (700px x 700px) floorplan i could draw circle in direct position example (50px , 75px) and it give the corect result in normal size of floorplan.
This circle is for show current location of user.

The question is how to position that circle if the image is scaled into 500x500 pixel with correct position same as (50px ,75px) in (700px x 700px) floorplan ?

Answer (score 0):

Dosn't this come down to a simple math problem?

The coordinates 50,75 in a 700*700 image would correspond to the coordinates 35(,71..), 53(,57..) in a 500*500 image. Fraction can be omitted, since, well, they're pixels.

The scaling factor would be 500/700 which is roughly 0,714. IE

```
ScalingFactor = NewDimension / OriginalDimension

ScaledPosition = OriginalPosition * ScalingFactor
```

This is obviously simplified because it is a square image, and scaling is the same among both sides.